# How to get the list of objects that have just been inserted into the table in the entity framework

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

> The best way to get object list has just been inserted into the
>   database?

I have the code to add a new object list to the database, I want to retrieve the list of objects without having to select again from the database.

I expect something like `insert` in the SQL Server trigger.

Here is my code snippet.

```
        List<string> productNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (var name in productNames)
        {
            var product = new Product {Name = name, Color = "something", Body="something body" };
            DbContext.Products.Add(product);
        }

        DbContext.SaveChanges();

        var result = ListProductsInserted; // I want to get list product
```

> I do not want to rewrite the query to retrieve data from the database
>   again.

Is there a better way?

Comment: if you keep the products you created in a list, their values will be updated after the .SaveChanges() call.

Comment: You can do it your list object and use ToList() Method `var result = ListProductsInserted.ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understaood your question properly, Use code below

```
List<string> productNames = new List<string>();
List<Product> holdProducts = new List<Product>();
foreach (var name in productNames)
{
    var product = new Product {Name = name, Color = "something", Body="something body" };
    DbContext.Products.Add(product);
    holdProducts.Add(product);
}
DbContext.SaveChanges();
var result = holdProducts;
```

Comment: You understand right, at first I do as you do, but I feel like it is not optimal, so I want to ask if there is a better way.
And it looks like this is pretty good. thank you

Comment: for Edit1: 
I want the result to be a list product, not a product list

Comment: holdProducts must be `List<product>` not `List<string>`

Comment: Oh I missed of few of things, However I have updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you would be [DbEntityEntry.Reload()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.reload(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry.Reload)

you can use it like this:

```
yourContext.Entry(yourEntity).Reload();
```